# Symfony + Travis-CI + Heroku + GitHub basic .gitignore and travis.yml?

Tags: php, heroku, github, symfony, travis-ci

I created a Symfony project with the composer command: "composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name" and I put it under version control using git and GitHub as remote hosting.
In addittion I need to use Travis-CI for continuous integration and status checking, together with Heroku for deployment.

Being the first time I use Symfony, travis and heroku I am having some trouble with their configuration files.

This is my .gitignore file:

```
/.idea
/app/config/parameters.yml
/build/
/phpunit.xml
/var/*
!/var/cache
/var/cache/*
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!/var/logs
/var/logs/*
!var/logs/.gitkeep
!/var/sessions
/var/sessions/*
!var/sessions/.gitkeep
!var/SymfonyRequirements.php
/vendor/
/web/bundles/
```

And this is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: php
php:
  - '5.5'
  - '5.6'
  - '7.0'
  - hhvm
  - nightly
```

[This is the log of travis-ci failing](https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/181209947/log.txt?deansi=true)

What I understood is that there is a lack of dependencies under vendor directory, which has been ignored by git due to solve the error message of heroku bild:

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Installing platform packages...
       - php (7.1.0)
       - apache (2.4.20)
       - nginx (1.8.1)
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 1.2.2 2016-11-03 17:43:15
 !     WARNING: Your Composer vendor dir is part of your Git repository.
       This directory should not be under version control; only your
       'composer.json' and 'composer.lock' files should be added, which
       will let Composer handle installation of dependencies on deploy.
       To suppress this notice, first remove the folder from your index
       by running 'git rm -r --cached vendor/'.
       Next, edit your project's '.gitignore' file and add the folder
       '/vendor/' to the list.
       For more info, refer to the Composer FAQ: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md
       Loading composer repositories with package information
       Installing dependencies from lock file
         - Removing symfony/phpunit-bridge (v3.1.7)
         - Removing sensio/generator-bundle (v3.1.1)
       Generating optimized autoload files
       > Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
       Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
       > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
       > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
       PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SensioGeneratorBundle" from namespace "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle".
       Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/app/AppKernel.php:25
       Stack trace:
       #0 /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(396): AppKernel->registerBundles()
       #1 /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(114): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
       #2 /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
       #3 /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Appli in /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/app/AppKernel.php on line 25
       Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception


         [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
         An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                                                                                            
         PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SensioGeneratorBundle" from namespace "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle".                                                 
         Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/app/AppKernel.php:25                                                                                   
         Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
         #0 /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(396): AppKernel->registerBundles()                                                          
         #1 /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(114): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()                              
         #2 /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()                             
         #3 /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Appli in /tmp/build_3481ed5a9ce634e19d2af5d00bd7a3f9/izio7-YourTeam-8f31587/app/AppKernel.php on line 25  
         .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    


       install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
 !     Push failed
```

Is there some command or change I can do, in order to make it work both with travis-ci and heroku without versioning the vendor directory or in some other way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by updating the .travis.yml with composer install.

```
language: php
php:
  - '5.5'
  - '5.6'
  - '7.0'
  - hhvm
  - nightly

before_script: composer install
```